# android view url in xml layout

Tags: android

I have a layout that I have set up with the android xml layout.  I would like to embed a link in a text view so that if you click on the link, it opens in the android browser.  how is that done.  There does not seem to be a url view or anything.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to just include the URL in the TextView and then [Linkify](http://d.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) it. There is also a [Tutorial about Linkify](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html) and custom links that might help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do this in a non-obvious but commonly desired way.  Let's say we want to linkify just the word *blammo* inside a textview.  When the user presses on *blammo*, a browser opens and sends them to *google.com*.

Try something like this:

```
class sampleTransformFilter implements TransformFilter {
    public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
        return "http://google.com";
    }
}

class sampleMatchFilter implements MatchFilter {
    public boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
        return true;
    }
}       

Pattern sampleMatcher = Pattern.compile("blammo");      
String sampleURL =    "";
Linkify.addLinks(textView, sampleMatcher, sampleURL, new sampleMatchFilter(), new sampleTransformFilter());
```